# function PHP copy(), copies file with hieroglyphics

Tags: php, download, http-headers, copy

I'm trying to copy css file from a link to my server (for example from this link https://ielm.nl/static/version1658321538/frontend/Zitec/ielm/default/css/styles-m.min.css), using copy(). And in principle the file is downloaded, but there are only hieroglyphs inside it...

[result after copying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESjaN.png)

The most interesting thing is that some css files it downloads fine, but the one from the link I provided below - with hieroglyphs

Here is the code:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                'header' => array('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.2) Gecko/20110201'),
            ),
        ));

copy('https://ielm.nl/static/version1658321538/frontend/Zitec/ielm/default/css/styles-m.min.css', $local_path, $context);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the contents are encoded as `gzip`. I would recommend doing the following:

```
file_put_contents($local_path, gzdecode(file_get_contents('https://ielm.nl/static/version1658321538/frontend/Zitec/ielm/default/css/styles-m.min.css')));
```